# Unable to set the image on the image view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, tags, uiimageview

In my app i am having a pop over controller which shows a bunch of images when clicked from other view.The other view have some images in it.All the images have a arrow button above them clicking on which the pop over gets displayed.let me come to the issue.say e.g i clicked the arrow button above the second image and pop over gets displayed .Now when i select any image from the pop over then i want to set that image to the image view present in the main view(or the image view which consist the arrow button).But what i am getting is that when i select any image from the pop over then it always gets set to the last image view present in the main view.I want to set it on the same image view above whose arrow button is clicked to display the pop over.

my code is:-

main view:--

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier] autorelease];

        UIImageView * imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 4, 80, 80)] autorelease];
        UIImageView * imageView2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,4,80, 80)] autorelease];
        UIImageView * imageView3 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(205,4, 80, 80)] autorelease];
        UIImageView * imageView4 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(295,4, 80, 80)] autorelease];

        imageView1.tag = j;
        imageView2.tag = j+1;
        imageView3.tag = j+2;
        imageView4.tag = j+3;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView3];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView4];   
    }

    for ( int i = 1; i <= j; i++ ) {
        imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:i];
        imageView.image=nill
    }

    int photosInRow;

    if ( (indexPath.row < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1) || ([sentence count] % 4 == 0) ) {
        photosInRow = 4;
    } else {
        photosInRow = [sentence count] % 4;
    }

    for ( int i = 1; i <=[sentence count]; i++ ){
        imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:i];

        [self setImage1:imageView];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Click event of the button:--

```
-(void)showPopOver:(id)sender
{
    ModalView *mvc = [[ModalView alloc]init];

    [mvc settingParentButton:imageView];
    [mvc settingPop:detailViewPopover]; 

    // Present the popover from the button that was tapped in the detail view.
    [detailViewPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0, 325, 650) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    // Set the last button tapped to the current button that was tapped.


    [mvc release];  
}
```

setting parent button event of modal view:--

```
-(void)settingParentButton:(UIImageView *)imageView {
    imageView1=imageView;
}
```

and did select row at index path of modal view:-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    NSLog(imageView1.tag);
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        [imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[nsmResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ];    
    }
    if (indexPath.row==1) {
        [imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[nsmResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ];    
    }
    if (indexPath.row==2) {
        [imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[nsmResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ];

    }
    if (indexPath.row==3) {
        [imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[nsmResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ];    
    }
    [pop2 dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Please help.Is it the tag issue ,please tell how can i check which tag is now in progress through which i can get the image view.Please answer.

Comment: @deepak-can u help me with this

Comment: When is `showPopOver` called?

Comment: it is called inside a button action click

Comment: How do you set `imageView`? Does it have anything to do with the button action?

Answer (score 0):

In that imageview while creating the memory allocation,autorelease should not be given,realease your memory in the dealloc, your expected image wil be placed in your occurences.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info



{
    UIImage *im =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


    self.imageView.image = im;

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(im, nil, nil, nil);

    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@interface testpViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

{
    IBOutlet    UIImageView     *imageView;
}

@property   (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView     *imageView;
```